# Angular page loads twice after Server Side Rendering

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I've implemented Server Side Rendering using Angular Universal,we've got a problem with our website,everything works correctly,but when loading the page,it loads twice.Everything was done according to Angular Universal guide for SSR,can anyone help me with this issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a very common issue with Angular Universal.

A server-rendered app shows a view of your app while the real client app loads, it’s just a static HTML page with styles until browser downloads client app scripts in background and Angular will show the dynamically rendered view of the live application. When the client apps render, it starts to re-run codes which in result it will issue HTTP requests again.

To solve this problem, you should use `TransferHttpCacheModule`, just follow the documents about how to implement it on your project. Link: https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/transfer-http.md

Comment: Yours is a partial solution: The flick goes away (visually) but the page still loads twice. I can tell very clearly in may case because i have css animations that are triggered just when the page loads and this happens twice. Even the flick is gone those animations should not start twice. I'm still fighting with this issue.

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution? I have the same issue as well.

Comment: Sure, It's more than a year I am using a solution. Just follow the link I shared on my answer, and read those comments on GitHub carefully to get the solution.

Comment: @MohammadKermani I used you solution. It doesnt work.

Comment: @PriyankaArora Hi! It's not my solution, it's the Angular Universal recommended solution. I'm not sure what's happening in your case, but you can probably ask a question on StackOverflow by sharing your code

Comment: This solution prevents flickering and makes some controls stop working as well. For example, all dropdowns are unable to show up after this. Actually, DOMContentLoaded isn't received, which means `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)` is not invoked.

Comment: @Capt.Michael This solution was working, and it was based on Angular documentation. It's good to check the link in the answer. Angular has changed a lot in past few years, I expect some slight changes to this solution, but it's best to check on their official documentation